# Integration of $\frac{x}{1-x\ln(x)}$

Tags: integration

I tried solve this question, but I have no idea after it.
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \int \frac{x}{1-x\ln x} \text{d}x \\
= & \int \frac{x-\ln x+\ln x}{1-x\ln x} \\
= & \int \frac{\frac{1}{x}(1-x\ln x)+\ln x}{1-x\ln x} \\
= & \int \frac{1}{x}\text{d}x+\int \frac{\ln x}{1-x\ln x} \text{d}x\\ 
= & \ln |x|+\int \frac{\ln x+1-1}{1-x\ln x} \text{d}x\\
= & \ln |x|-\int \frac{\text{d}(1-x\ln x)}{1-x\ln x}-\int \frac{\text{d}x}{1-x\ln x} \\
= & \ln \left|\frac{x}{1-x\ln x}\right|-\int \frac{\text{d}x}{1-x\ln x}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: $\frac{1}{x}(1-x\ln x)=\frac{1}{x}-\ln x \ne x-\ln x$

Comment: Why do you suspect that this has a nice closed form?

Comment: @Vasya Well, I made a low-level mistake.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Emmm, because it comes from my homework

Comment: Wolfram alpha says there is no result in terms of standard mathematical functions... https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=indefinite+integral+of+x%2F%281-xlnx%29

Comment: Try $$\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{n\ge 0} x^n,|x|<1$$

Comment: @SilveryStar Your homework must contain a typo, or your post contains a typo, because it is impossible to antidifferentiate this function, unless you use some special functions that I doubt even your teacher is acquainted with.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for $0<x<e^\Omega=\frac1\Omega$, with the [Omega constant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_constant) using [Geometric Series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series):

$$\int \frac x{1-x\ln(x)}dx=\int x\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \ln^n(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int x^{n+1}\ln^n(x)dx\mathop=^{x\to e^x}C- \sum_{n=0}^\infty \ln^{n+1}(x)\text E_{-n}(-(n+2)\ln(x))\mathop=^{x\ne0}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\Gamma(n+1,-(n+2)\ln(x))}{(n+2)^{n+1}}$$

where [$\text E_a(b)$ is the En function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/En-Function.html) and the [$\Gamma(a,b)$ is the Incomplete Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) of which the sums probably have no closed form. Please correct me and give me feedback!